# Display bill total, Java public void display() error

Tags: java, void, public

I'm having some trouble executing the total bill display. I asked my professor who gave me this small block of code, which I modified to meet my needs, but for some reason it is not executing and has the error:

> Illegal start to expression for line --> public void display().

The compiler also suggests to end with a semi colon which I don't believe is accurate.

What am I missing that `public void display()` is not being executed and is erroneous?

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoffeeShop

{
/* Author: 
   Date: 
   Program: Create a Coffee Shop application that uses a while loop to build a customer order. The Coffee Shops sells coffee ($3.25), espresso ($4.25), and tea ($2.75). The coffee selection presents the customer with the choices of iced (no charge), cream (50 cents), and sugar (50 cents). The espresso selection presents the customer with choice of caramel (no charge) and chocolate (no charge) with one shot (no charge) or two shots ($1.25) of espresso. Once the customer is done, he or she will receive a bill of the total price. After each selection, the customer will have the choice of returning to the main menu for additional purchases. Use nested loops to handle customers' submenu selections.
*/   
   public static void main(String[] args)

   {

   //declarations
      double coff = 3.25;
      double esp = 4.25;
      double tea = 2.75;
      double cream = .50;
      double sugar = .50;
      double dblShot = 1.25;
      int dblshotQty = 0;
      int userInput = 0;
      int userInput2 = 0;
      int coffQty = 0;
      int espQty = 0;
      int teaQty = 0;
      int creamQty = 0;
      int sugarQty = 0;
      double runTotal = 0;
      double totalCoff = 0;
      double totalEsp = 0;
      double totalTea = 0;
      double totalBill = 0;






      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Would you like to place an order? press 1 for yes or 2 for no :");
      //start a loop with a control variable asking if they would like a cup of coffee yes or no
      userInput = scan.nextInt();
      while(userInput == 1)
      {

         System.out.print("Enter 1 for Coffee, 2 for Espresso, or 3 for tea: ");

         userInput2 = scan.nextInt();
         switch(userInput2)
         //if 1 is pressed coffee is ordered
         { // open switch
            case '1':
               {
                  coffQty = coffQty + 1;
                  System.out.print("Press 1 if you would like your coffee iced or 2 for no: ");
                  userInput = scan.nextInt();
               }
               {
                  System.out.print("Press 1 if you would like cream for $.50 or 2 for no: ");   
                  userInput = scan.nextInt();
                  if ( userInput == 1 )
                  {
                     creamQty = creamQty + 1;
                  }
               }  
               {
                  System.out.print("Press 1 if you would like sugar for $.50 or 2 for no: ");
                  userInput = scan.nextInt();
                  if ( userInput == 1 )
                  {
                     sugarQty = sugarQty + 1;
                  }
               }//end case 1
               break;

         // espresso is ordered ask for double shot
            case '2':   
               {
                  espQty = espQty +1;
                  System.out.println("Press 1 for a double shot for $1.25 or 2 for no: ");
                  userInput = scan.nextInt();
                  if(userInput == 1)
                  {
                     dblshotQty = dblshotQty +1;
                  }   

               }//end case 2
               break;

         //tea is ordered
            case '3':
               {
                  teaQty = teaQty + 1;
                  System.out.println("You have selected tea! Great Choice.");
               }//end case 3  
         }//end switch


      // create output display for total bill adding all totals


   public void display()
   {
      double totalCoff = coffQty * coff + cream * creamQty + sugar * sugarQty;
      double totalEsp =  espQty * esp + dblshot * dblshotQty;
      double totalTea = teaQty * tea;

      System.out.println("Order: \n "+coffQty + " Coffee"
            + "\n "+creamQty +" Cream"
            + "\n "+sugarQty + " Sugar"
            + "\nTotal Coffee: "+ totalCoff);
      System.out.println(" "+teaQty + " Tea"
            + "\nTotal Tea: "+ totalTea);
      System.out.println(" "+espQty + " Espresso"
            + "\n "+dblshotQty +" Double shot"
            + "\nTotal Espresso: "+ totalEsp);
      double totalBill = totalCoff+totalEsp+totalTea;
      System.out.println("\nTotal drink order: "+totalBill);
   }



      break;
    } // end while
   }



} // end of class
```

Comment: You have an error on the line above. Show the code above this function.

Comment: You don't have to explain the background. Just state the problem as concisely (yet clearly) as possible so we don't have to sift through it

Comment: Agreed with @Carcigenicate. Usually, "Illegal start of line" means that there's something on the previous line interfering with the parsing of this line. For instance, a missing semicolon or bracket, or simply an incomplete statement.

Comment: Thank you Tim Castelijns, I will keep it brief in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few main problems:

1. You defined `display` inside of `main`, inside of a while loop. You can't define methods inside of methods, let alone inside of loops. Move `display` outside of `main`, but still inside the class.
2. You have a misplaced `break` floating around under `display`. Get rid of that, as that will also be an error.
3. As @MiiinimalLogic pointed out, you're relying on data from `main` inside of `display`. You'll need to pass the data from `main` to `display` as arguments.

Comment: I did attempt to put the display outside the first curly bracket and inside the class, I'm still getting the same error. Should I move my declarations to the class area ( the first curly bracket under public main static void )

Comment: @Elements It's hard to tell exactly what's going on with your code because your indentation is off, but yes, display should be under `main`, but inside the class.

Comment: @Elements also, that random `break` under `display` needs to be removed. That will cause an error too.

Comment: I do apologize I put the code with decent indentation but It would not let me post without moving everything left. I can understand your frustration and appreciate the guidance!

Comment: @Elements Once you paste the code, highlight it and press ctrl+k to auto-format it.

Comment: @Elements I also just noticed you have `display` defined inside of a while loop. That's illegal too. See my updated answer.

Comment: fudge son of a something, you guys/gals are correct. I have to put the logic inside the main or reformat the whole code. Well at least I got my answer! Thanks everyone I couldn't be more illegal if I tried!

Comment: @Elements Just pass the data as arguments to display, unless your teacher requires that display must take 0 arguments.

Comment: There are no special requirements besides make it work and properly with the noted details bill total and what was ordered. I'm looking into passing the data now the terms are still a little Greek to me.

Comment: @Elements Definitely understand how to pass data as arguments into a function. That's easily one of the more important things every newbie should grasp.

Comment: @Elements And the terminology is simpler than some tutorials may make it seem. Say you have `System.out.println("Hello")`. `System.out.println` is the function, and `"Hello"` is the argument; it's the data you're giving the function. `System.out.println` takes that data, and uses it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code structure is making things difficult for you.  As mentioned by @Carcigenicate, (nice name btw), you have you declared a method inside the main method.  Once you change that, you'll notice now that now the `display` method shows compiler errors. This is because the variables referenced in `display` are no longer visible. You have a few options:

- Rethink the design of the class i.e What methods should exist and how they will be called.
- Take the display method outside the main method and then make the variables member variables that are visible to the methods you need.  Read about the effects of using member variables first.
- Remove the display method completely and move the logic to the main method.

Comment: Not sure if that comment is sarcasm or not. I've had people offended at it before, so I never know.

Comment: Haha no its awesome..sometimes I feel like staring at my monitor is carcinogenic so I'm w/ ya..

Comment: OK good lol. I needed a made up word for my username, and it sounded cool. I never meant it to be linked to cancer, despite the root word in there.

Comment: There'd have to be a formal, scientific study to link you to cancer so you're good bra :p !!